# CakePHP - How check layout of action?

Tags: cakephp, layout

In action, I'm using `$this->layout = 'admin'` to call default layout "admin.ctp". Now, I want to check when I access an action, I will know that action is using what layout.

Actually, I have to get the name of layout when I access an action through beforeFilter().

Thanks!

**Solve:**

I have just checked $this->layout in beforeRender(), and I had knew the layout of action before View is rendered :)

Comment: I assume that you need to change the layout based on your action name ? Right ?

Answer (score 1):

change the design of your layouts, then you can identify what layout you are using. :)

Comment: you misunderstood, I want to check permission through beforeFilter and have to know the default layout of action is using.

Comment: It may not be a _good_ answer, but it is _an_ answer.   This answer says "modify some layout code, then see what appears, to see what layout is being used".   If you think this is a bad answer, vote it down.